# NE555 Timer Problem

Tags: led, capacitor, resistors, 555

I need help using an NE555 timer to flash an LED.
Here is my current set up:
[image: img 1]
[image: img 2]
All resistors are 220 Ohms and LED is [link](http://www.taydaelectronics.com/leds/round-leds/5mm-leds/blue/led-5mm-blue-water-clear-ultra-bright.html)
The capacitor is 10uf and same result happens with 1uf. I am using a 9V battery.

Description: The LED Blinks on when given power and stays off indefinitely immediately after turning on.

Comment: It looks like your resistor from pin 6 goes nowhere. You're putting power into the second row, but seem to have the resistor plugged into the first row. It's difficult to see in your pictures, but you may have the same problem with the capacitor on the bottom row.

Comment: Yeah I just double checked and its all connected, I mean I probably am just screwing up the resistances and such

Comment: If you could provide a schematic and clean up your wiring it'd be much easier to see where you've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has trouble, watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJa0oiV6B24) and make sure your capacitor is big enough since the timer works based off of how full it is.

Comment: If you had to make the capacitor larger to *see* the blinking, **it was already working**, it was just flashing too fast to see. You could achieve the same effect by making some of the resistors larger.